# Can't scale image to fit screen. Tried resizeMode and aspectRatio. How do I scale to fit?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am setting up a image display.  The images are dispalyed correctly.  However there is unwanted large extra area I highlighted in grey color.  How do I get rid of that area.  This code is written in react-native.

I have tried to use aspectRadio.  It stretch to cover the entire grey area however only part of image is shown.
Also tried resizeMode = "cover" same thing happened above.
Tried to hide overflow, nothing change

```
render(){

        let aspect = null
        let imgW = null
        let imgH = null
        if (this.props.image){
            imgW = this.props.image.width
            imgH = this.props.image.height
            aspect = imgW / imgH
        }
        console.log(aspect)

        return(

            <View>
                <Image source={this.props.image} style={[styles.image]} />
                <Text>{this.props.description}</Text>



            </View>
        )
    }

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
    },
    image:{
        resizeMode: 'contain',
        width: '100%',
        backgroundColor: '#D8D8D8',
    }
})
```

I expect only the image shown in this aspect radio which is correct.  Only image without the extra space.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUm76.png)

Comment: Worth mentioning.  I used react-native-image-picker to pick my images and set maxWidth and maxHeight to 800.  I tried to set aspectRatio in a <View> with result height and width.  The <View> showed correct ratio.  This problem occurs only when I display those images

Comment: If a `View` is showing the correct ratio, what if you wrap the `Image` within that `View`?

Comment: I tried it earlier.  Maybe I did something wrong but I’ll try again.  So what happen here is that the image actually expand and cover the text below.  I forgot if the entire image was shown though.

Comment: I got it working by wrapping the image with <View> with the correct aspect ratio and then set width and height to 100% and resizeMode contain

Answer (score 0):

did you try this?

```
  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
    },
    image: {
      flex: 1,
      resizeMode: 'cover', // or 'stretch'
    },
  });
```

Comment: I tried it and tried again.  The image was enlarged to cover the grey area.  Only part of image was shown.  The rest was gone.

Comment: I also tried strech earlier.  The image was stretched to fill the grey area.  The aspect ratio became completely wrong, even if I set it with original image width and height

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide height/flex and width to your container.Also resize mode is a prop not a style property

```
  render() {
    let aspect = null;
    let imgW = null;
    let imgH = null;
    if (this.props.image) {
      imgW = this.props.image.width;
      imgH = this.props.image.height;
      aspect = imgW / imgH;
    }
    console.log(aspect);

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image
          source={this.props.image}
          style={[styles.image, { height: imgH }]}
          resizeMode={"contain"}
        />
        <Text>{this.props.description}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    width: "100%"
  },
  image: {
    width: "100%",
    backgroundColor: "#D8D8D8"
  }
});
```

Comment: I just tried this code.  It produces the same result as the inital problem.  Grey space doesn't change

Comment: You can't keep the aspect ration intact and still fill the gray area with the same image then. resizeMode : contain takes the lower of your width and height and sets the other with respect to it. It cannot/ will not cover the screen.All you can do to cover the screen is set resizeMode to stretch